# Javascript: Get the array where a specific value in the array contains word (tags)

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, tags

I have this array:

```
[{
  "title": "Pirates of the Caribbean 5",
  "others": "lorem",
  "tags": "action,experimental,comedy"
},
{
  "title": "Toy Story 3",
  "others": "lorem",
  "tags": "animation,family,comedy"
},
{
  "title": "Pirates of the Caribbean 1",
  "others": "lorem",
  "tags": "action,adventure,comedy"
}]
```

and **I am trying to get the all details (title,others) where the tag is *action***.

To find whether a string contains action i do this:

```
$.getJSON('jsonpath.json', function(data) {
            var items = [];

            $.each(data, function(count,item) {
                var a = $.inArray("action", item.tags.split(","));

                if (a != -1){
                    console.log("Found")
                }

            });


        });
```

What do I do after here to append/parse the title's and other's of films tagged with action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your intent.

You can access the title with `item.title` (inside the each() loop) and others with `item.others`

Comment: I want to append all titles with tag action. That's all

Comment: Sorry this was a mistaken question basically. Feelings kinda tired. Please do mark it as closed.

Answer (score 0):

push the item to items array once it is found.

```
 var items = [];
 $.getJSON('jsonpath.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(count,item) {
            var a = $.inArray("action", item.tags.split(","));

            if (a != -1){
                console.log("Found");
                items.push(item);
            } 
        });
    });
```